# Get href tag inner text from html (html agility pack)

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am successfully extracting the file names from all href tags in the html below and add it to a list.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="resourcelist">
    <li><a href="/upload/Article/07.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="/assets/images/pdf.png" /> <strong>SPEC SHEET: </strong> d07</a></li>
    <li><a href="/upload/Article/73.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="/assets/images/pdf.png" /> <strong>ASSEMBLY SHEET: </strong> d73</a></li>
    <li><a href="/upload/Article/75.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="/assets/images/pdf.png" /> <strong>ASSEMBLY SHEET: </strong> d75</a></li>
    <li><a href="/upload/Article/71.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="/assets/images/pdf.png" /> <strong>INSTALLATION SHEET: </strong> d71</a></li>
</ul>
```

**C# code to parse the html:**

```
    public List<string> LinksList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> GetLinks()
        {
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(GetProductDescription("TechnicalSpecifications"));
            HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                var href = node.Attributes["href"].Value.Split('/')[3];
                if (!LinksList.Contains(href))
                {
                    LinksList.Add(href);
                }

            }
            return LinksList;
        }
```

Is there any possible way to target everything from the beginning  of `<strong>` + the text before closing a tag? (basically everything that is not in < ... >)

I have looked over tons of questions on SO nothing seems to be the answer for this.

**Output example:**

SPEC SHEET: d07

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're effectively  just collecting the inner text of the nodes. Do this:

```
var texts = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
    .Select(n => n.InnerText)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Jeff!

Comment: what is the purpose of _.Cast<HtmlNode>_ please? I see it referenced here: https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/655603/html-agility-pack---parsing-tables  but it doesn't specifically talk about what is being done. It is handling the LINQ-to-Objects conversion?

Comment: @QHarr: Actually it seems like the cast call is unnecessary here. Maybe once upon a time, it was, it's been a long time since I last used HtmlAgilityPack, or I might be mixing up how other libraries behaved. If I'm not mistaken, `HtmlNodeCollection` only implemented (non-generic) `IEnumerable` which doesn't work with linq. So the `IEnumerable` would have to be `Cast<>()` to `IEnumerable<HtmlNode>`. But I guess this has changed since I last remembered.

Comment: @QHarr: So it looks like the cast was needed in versions prior to 1.4. But we're now in 1.11 and that was a long time ago.